# Zend Form - Add a <div> around the input element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm using Zend Framework 2 Form to render my forms, and Bootstrap 3 to style them.
I want to use the Horizontal Form Layout as explained here:
[Bootstrap 3 Forms tutorial](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php)

To do so, I need to add a div with appropriate classes around the input element; is there any easy way to add such div while adding the new element to the Form class? My element so far:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'id' => 'contactName',
        'maxlength' => '70',
        'placeholder' => 'Your full name.',
        'class' => 'form-control'
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Name: ',
        'label_attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-2'
        )
    ),
));
```

Can I add anything here to easily add `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10"></div>` around the input element when I render it with `<?php echo $this->formRow($this->form->get('name')); ?>`?

Comment: Actually, ZF2's form view helpers are not bootstrap friendly and rendering various form elements bootstrap-way is requires more effort than you think. I strongly recommend using of [ZF2 Twb Module](https://github.com/neilime/zf2-twb-bundle) for this job. Check-out [this online demo](http://neilime.github.io/zf2-twb-bundle/demo.html).

Comment: Luckily I found out how to render the different parts of a form element separately, so I could write a simple View Helper to solve my problem. Sad to hear confirmation that there was no easier way to go. The module you recommended looks very interesting and I'll surely give it a deeper look if I'll have any other similar problems, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem by creating a custom View Helper:

```
public function __invoke($element) {
echo '<div class="form-group">';
echo $this->view->formLabel($element);
echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">' . $this->view->formElement($element) . '</div>';
echo $this->view->formElementErrors($element);
echo '</div>';
}
```

Though I still wonder if there was another easier way to do that!

Comment: Adding a helper is the way to go.  Please accept your own answer so the question doesn't go on appearing as unanswered.